# unable to override styles in react material-ui appbar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have made a custom component and I tried to use it in AppBar but the Styles are not overwritten. I have used makeStyles hook and it is working fine when I use it outside but when I use it in AppBar and ToolBar, I am not able to overwrite UI.

Here is my codeSandBox Link: https://codesandbox.io/s/inquisitorius-6l721?file=/src/Links/Links.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding zIndex to `links` would solve that:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
  links: {
    zIndex: 0,
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see that the same styling is applied to the Link in the AppBar too, however you can't see the underlining because of the negative z-index.

Comment: Ok, now I understood. Thank you so much